# Dataframe's replace method behaving weird

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset and want to replace the 0's of a particular column with None.

```
diabetes_data = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/npradaschnor/Pima-Indians-Diabetes-Dataset/master/diabetes.csv")
temp = diabetes_data.copy()
null_index = diabetes_data[diabetes_data["Glucose"]==0].index
print(diabetes_data.loc[null_index])
```

[image: Output of original DataFrame]

Then I use the `replace` method and try to replace `0` with `None`

```
temp["Glucose"] = diabetes_data["Glucose"].replace(0, None)
print(temp.loc[null_index])
```

[image: Output of temp dataframe]

In the above image it can be seen that the values are not replaced with `None`, also I am not sure what these values are.

But when I pass the arguments to `replace` function as a list then it works as expected.

```
temp1 = diabetes_data.copy()
temp1["Glucose"].replace([0], [None], inplace=True)
temp1.loc[null_index]
```

[image: Output when parameters are passed as list]

Above is the output I expect.
The documentation for `replace` says that it accepts `int` as well.

So I am not able to understand why is it giving weird result when `int` is passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of replacing `0` by `None`, we can use `numpy.nan` like so :

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> temp["Glucose"] = diabetes_data["Glucose"].replace(0, np.nan)
>>> temp.loc[null_index]
        Pregnancies     Glucose     BloodPressure   SkinThickness   Insulin     BMI     DiabetesPedigreeFunction    Age     Outcome
75      1               NaN         48              20              0           24.7    0.140                       22      0
182     1               NaN         74              20              23          27.7    0.299                       21      0
342     1               NaN         68              35              0           32.0    0.389                       22      0
349     5               NaN         80              32              0           41.0    0.346                       37      1
502     6               NaN         68              41              0           39.0    0.727                       41      1
```

### What is going on:

The first two arguments to [`.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) are `to_replace`, and `values`, **both of which default to `None`.**

When you explicitly pass `None` as the second argument (i.e. for `values`), then **there is no difference from just calling the replace function without the `values` argument at all**. Without any further arguments passed, calling `.replace` will refer to the **`method` argument: which defaults to `pad`**: a probably very undesired effect in this case.

This means the issue isn't to do with the fact you're using `int`, it's to do with the value you're trying to replace the `int` with.

### An example from the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

This case is actually explicitly explained in the documentation, and a workaround **using a dictionary argument is provided:**

> Compare the behavior of s.replace({'a': None}) and s.replace('a', None) to understand the peculiarities of the to_replace parameter:

```py
>>> s = pd.Series([10, 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a'])
```

> When one uses a dict as the *to_replace* value, it is like the value(s) in the dict are equal to the *value* parameter. `s.replace({'a': None})` is equivalent to `s.replace(to_replace={'a': None}, value=None, method=None)`:

```py
s.replace({'a': None})
0      10
1    None
2    None
3       b
4    None
dtype: object
```

> When `value=None` and *to_replace* is a scalar, list or tuple, *replace* uses the method parameter (default ‘pad’) to do the replacement. So this is why the ‘a’ values are being replaced by 10 in rows 1 and 2 and ‘b’ in row 4 in this case. The command `s.replace('a', None)` is actually equivalent to `s.replace(to_replace='a', value=None, method='pad')`:

```py
s.replace('a', None)
0    10
1    10
2    10
3     b
4     b
dtype: object
```

Comment: I tried the code and as @learnToCode said it doesn't work. Using `np.nan` works directly. Yes I tried it :), the code displayed in this answer comes from my side.

Comment: Check dupe, there is it explain like need OP.

Comment: Yes good idea, I look for it because I can't explain it.

Comment: Seems this is copied from dupe... Is possible convert to wiki?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't think that I have enough reputation to do such a thing. I am checking what convert to wiki means in the SO doc.

Comment: @jezrael The values the OP sees are ffill (`pad`) values, from the source: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L6472

Comment: Do you try it? check EDIT and then convert to Community wiki under answer.

Comment: Instead of `convert to wiki` I have a `community wiki` checkbox under my answer, it says that by checking that I will lose some reputation point. Should I do it ?

Comment: @jezrael as you asked me to do so, I did convert it, hope it is better now.

Comment: @tlentali - Sure, you lost it, by I can motivite you some way for not lost ;)